# Quick way to list all files in Amazon S3 bucket using php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I have an amazon s3 bucket that has tens of thousands of filenames in it. What's the easiest way to get a list of all file or text file that lists all the filenames in the bucket?

I have tried with `listObject()`, but It seems that it only list 1000 files.

[amazon-s3-returns-only-1000-entries-for-one-bucket-and-all-for-another-bucket-u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853476/amazon-s3-returns-only-1000-entries-for-one-bucket-and-all-for-another-bucket-u)
[S3-Provider-does-not-get-more-than-1000-items-from-bucket](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/universal-media-picker/bugs,-feedback-and-suggestions/29133-S3-Provider-does-not-get-more-than-1000-items-from-bucket)

--> [Listing Keys Using the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingPHP.html)
but in aws docs I read

> max-keys - string - Optional - The maximum number of results returned
>   by the method call. The returned list will contain no more results
>   than the specified value, but may return fewer. The default value is
>   1000.

[AWS DOC FOR list_objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/list_objects)

> **Is there some way to list it all and print it to a text file using AWS PHP SDK ?**

**Possible repeat :** [quick-way-to-list-all-files-in-amazon-s3-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337912/quick-way-to-list-all-files-in-amazon-s3-bucket)

I have reposted the question because am looking for the solution in php.

**Code :**

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array('key' => $access, 'secret' => $secret));

$response = $s3Client->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucket, 'MaxKeys' => 1000, 'Prefix' => 'files/'));
$files = $response->getPath('Contents');
$request_id = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = $file['Key'];
    print "\n\nFilename:". $filename;

 }
```

Comment: Note that in newer versions of the PHP SDK the client must be created like this instead: `$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array('credentials' => array('key' => $access, 'secret' => $secret)));`

Comment: @TheStoryCoder : Thanks for information

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get more than 1000 objects, you must make multiple requests using the `Marker` parameter to tell S3 where you left off for each request. Using the [Iterators](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-iterators.html) feature of the AWS SDK for PHP makes it easier to get all of your objects, because it encapsulates the logic of making multiple API requests. Try this:

```
$objects = $s3Client->getListObjectsIterator(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => 'files/'
));

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
}
```

With latest PHP SDK (as of March 2016) the code must be written like this instead:

```
$objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => 'files/'
));
```

Comment: you are little late, I too found the same but Thanks a lot,  I did do some work around in this to make it work for me but as I found that each request only list 1000 and if you are doing any search (lets assume for only pdf files, it searches from those 1000 results) so, still I can not be sure about the count but I have found this is the only trick to do this

Comment: @jermy : which one u will recommend your answer or mine ? and why ?

Comment: I would say that mine would be better for the following reasons:
1.) It requires fewer requests. Given that `n` is the total number of S3 objects in your bucket with the `files/` prefix, my solution requires ceil(n/1000) requests. Yours always requires exactly 52 requests, whether or not they are all needed.
2.) Mine only requires one loop instead of 2 loops with nested loops.
3.) If you had more than 1000 files that started with a particular letter, your solution only captures the first 1000 per letter. Mine will always get all of your objects.

Comment: I think to get the full URL you can just do this: 

    sprintf('http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s', $bucket_name, $object['Key'])

Answer (score 9):

Use Paginator to get all files

```
    $client = new S3Client([
        'version' => AWS_S3_CLIENT_FACTORY_VERSION,
        'region' => AWS_S3_CLIENT_FACTORY_REGION,

    ]);
    $objects = $client->getPaginator('ListObjects', ['Bucket' => "my-bucket"]);
    foreach ($objects as $listResponse) {
        $items = $listResponse->search("Contents[?starts_with(Key,'path/to/folder/')]");
        foreach($items as $item) {
            echo $item['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

To get all files change the search to:

```
$listResponse->search("Contents[*]");
```

Comment: This method is extremely slow if there is thousands of objects already present.  Do you have a faster method?

Answer (score 1):

Below code is just one trick, work around for this problem, I have pointed to my **`CDN bucket`** folder which have lot of folder alphabetically (a-z & A-Z), so I just made a multiple requests to make it list all files,

**`This code is to list mp4, pdf, png, jpg or all files`**

```
//letter range a-z and A-Z
$az = range('a', 'z');
$AZ = range('A', 'Z');
//To get the total no of files
$total = 0;
//text file
$File = "CDNFileList.txt"; 

//getting dropdownlist values 
$selectedoption = $_POST['cdn_dropdown_list'];
$file_ext = '';
if ($selectedoption == 'pdf'){
    $file_ext = 'PDF DOCUMENTS';
}else if(($selectedoption == 'jpg')){
    $file_ext = 'JPEG IMAGES';
}else if(($selectedoption == 'png')){
    $file_ext = 'PNG IMAGES';
}else if($selectedoption == 'mp4'){
    $file_ext = 'MP4 VIDEOS';
}else if($selectedoption == 'all'){
    $file_ext = 'ALL CONTENTS';
}
//Creating table
echo "<table style='width:300px' border='1'><th colspan='2'><b>List of $file_ext</b></th><tr><td><b>Name of the File</b></td><td><b>URL of the file</b></td></tr>";

foreach($az as $value){
        $response = $s3Client->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucket, 'MaxKeys' => 1000, 'Prefix' => 'files/'.$value));
        $files = $response->getPath('Contents');
        $file_list = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
                $filename = $file['Key'];
                if ( 'all' == ($selectedoption)){
                        $file_path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
                        $file_name = $file_path_parts['filename'];
                        echo "<tr><td>$file_name</td><td><a href = '";
                        echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                        echo "' target='_blank'>";
                        echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                        echo "</a></td></tr>";
                        $filename = $baseUrl.$filename.PHP_EOL; 
                        array_push($file_list, $filename);
                        $total++;
                }else{
                    $filetype = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.')+1));
                    if ($filetype == ($selectedoption)){
                        $file_path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
                        $file_name = $file_path_parts['filename'];
                        echo "<tr><td>$file_name</td><td><a href = '";
                        echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                        echo "' target='_blank'>";
                        echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                        echo "</a></td></tr>";
                        $filename = $baseUrl.$filename.PHP_EOL; 
                        array_push($file_list, $filename);
                        $total++;
                    }
                }
        }
}

foreach($AZ as $value){
        $response = $s3Client->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucket, 'MaxKeys' => 1000, 'Prefix' => 'files/'.$value));
        $files = $response->getPath('Contents');
        $file_list = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file['Key'];
            if ( 'all' == ($selectedoption)){
                    $file_path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
                    $file_name = $file_path_parts['filename'];
                    echo "<tr><td>$file_name</td><td><a href = '";
                    echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                    echo "' target='_blank'>";
                    echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                    echo "</a></td></tr>";
                    $filename = $baseUrl.$filename.PHP_EOL; 
                    array_push($file_list, $filename);
                    $total++;
            }else{
                $filetype = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.')+1));
                if ($filetype == ($selectedoption)){
                    $file_path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
                    $file_name = $file_path_parts['filename'];
                    echo "<tr><td>$file_name</td><td><a href = '";
                    echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                    echo "' target='_blank'>";
                    echo $baseUrl.$filename;
                    echo "</a></td></tr>";
                    $filename = $baseUrl.$filename.PHP_EOL; 
                    array_push($file_list, $filename);
                    $total++;
                }
            }
        }
}
echo "</table><br/>";
print "\n\nTOTAL NO OF $file_ext ".$total;
```

This is just a workaround for this problem,Since there is no `AWS API` to list all the files (more than 1000). hope it helps someone.

Comment: I am getting error while i am listing S3 objects.PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\PermanentRedirectException: AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, Status Code: 301,

Comment: AWS Request ID: E07DWDWED, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint: "images.cser.in.s3.amazonaws.com"., User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.7.27 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.40.0 PHP/5.5.31 ITR

Comment: thrown in /var/www/html/app/s3/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91

Comment: please ask the question in SO describing the scenario. If you have already asked the question, share the link