# Counting keys in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Using the boto3 library and python code below, I can iterate through S3 buckets and prefixes, printing out the prefix name and key name as follows:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')

pfx_paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pfx_iterator = pfx_paginator.paginate(Bucket='app_folders', Delimiter='/')
for prefix in pfx_iterator.search('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(prefix['Prefix'])

    key_paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    key_iterator = key_paginator.paginate(Bucket='app_folders', Prefix=prefix['Prefix'])
    for key in key_iterator.search('Contents'):
        print(key['Key'])
```

Inside the key loop, I can put in a counter to count the number of keys (files), but this is an expensive operation.  Is there a  way to make one call given a bucket name and a prefix and return the count of keys contained in that prefix (even if it is more than 1000)?

UPDATE: I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862617/how-can-i-tell-how-many-objects-ive-stored-in-an-s3-bucket) that shows a way to do this with the AWS CLI as follows:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --prefix "folder/subfolder/" --output json --query "[length(Contents[])]"
```

Is there a way to do something similar with the boto3 API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the size of a boto3 Collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408167/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-boto3-collection)

Comment: `aws s3api` is just paginating for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `MaxKeys=1000` parameter.
For your case:

```
pfx_iterator = pfx_paginator.paginate(Bucket='app_folders', Delimiter='/', MaxKeys=1000)
```

In general:

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='string',
    Delimiter='string',
    EncodingType='url',
    MaxKeys=123,
    Prefix='string',
    ContinuationToken='string',
    FetchOwner=True|False,
    StartAfter='string',
    RequestPayer='requester'
)
```

It will be cheaper for you in 1000 times :)
[Documentation here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)

Answer (score 0):

Using aws cli it is easy to count :

```
aws s3 ls  <folder url> --recursive --summarize | grep <comment>
```

e.g.,

```
aws s3 ls  s3://abc/ --recursive --summarize | grep "Number of Objects"
```